# Gimp plugin Bimp - problem with config

Tags: 15.04, plugins, gimp

I have problem with bimp plugin, its a gimp plugin for batch image manipulation [[download link]](https://github.com/alessandrofrancesconi/gimp-plugin-bimp/releases/tag/v1.15). After installation its works only when i run gimp from terminal as root - when i run it from icon, plugin is inactive. Can you please help me understand why its works like that and what is an issue ?

Its how i install this plugin:

1. Download tar
2. Unzip
3. `Sudo -i` and then navigate to  plugin folder
4. `make && make install, apt-get upgrade && update`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in the `README.md` file, you should **either** run

```
make
make install
```

to install the plugin in your own `~/.gimp-2.8/plug-ins` directory, **or** run

```
make
sudo make install-admin
```

to install system-wide. **Do not** make the plain `install` target with sudo, since this will place a root-owned version of the plugin into your home directory.

Comment: Ok, seems you're right, deleted my answer.

Comment: Okey, thank you for help, how can i undone this what i already did ? Im quite now in linux .

Comment: Use the chown command to make your own user and group the owner of the installed plug-in file.